# window shrinks when label is packed, even though textbox is bigger

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to add a hyperlink style overlay at the bottom of a scrolled textbox to show like a statusbar type label when the user moves the mouse over a hyperlink (like a webbrowser shows the link address in the bottom left). I've started with the hyperlink manager code from effbot and modified it to add bits for the callback to set the text:

```
try:
    from tkinter import scrolledtext
except ImportError:
    import ScrolledText as scrolledtext

class HyperlinkManager(object):
    """A class to easily add clickable hyperlinks to Text areas.
    Usage:
      callback = lambda : webbrowser.open("http://www.google.com/")
      text = tk.Text(...)
      hyperman = tkHyperlinkManager.HyperlinkManager(text)
      text.insert(tk.INSERT, "click me", hyperman.add(callback))
    From http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-hyperlink.htm
    """
    def __init__(self, text, statusfunc=None):
        self.text = text
        self.statusfunc = statusfunc
        self.text.tag_config("hyper", foreground="blue", underline=1)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Enter>", self._enter)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Leave>", self._leave)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Button-1>", self._click)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.links = {}

    def add(self, action, tooltip=None):
        """Adds an action to the manager.
        :param action: A func to call.
        :return: A clickable tag to use in the text widget.
        """
        tag = "hyper-%d" % len(self.links)
        self.links[tag] = [action, tooltip]
        return ("hyper", tag)

    def _enter(self, event):
        self.text.config(cursor="hand2")
        for tag in self.text.tag_names(tk.CURRENT):
            if (tag[:6] == "hyper-"):
                tooltip = self.links[tag][1]
                if self.statusfunc:
                    self.statusfunc(tooltip) # don't care if no tooltip as function clears if it doesn't
                return

    def _leave(self, event):
        self.text.config(cursor="")
        if self.statusfunc:
            self.statusfunc()

    def _click(self, event):
        for tag in self.text.tag_names(tk.CURRENT):
            if (tag[:6] == "hyper-"):
                func = self.links[tag][0]
                if func:
                    func()
                return

class LinkScrolledText(scrolledtext.ScrolledText):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        scrolledtext.ScrolledText.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.status = tk.Label(self)
        self._hyper = HyperlinkManager(self, self.showstatus)
        self.reset_links()

    def showstatus(self, status=None):
        print("showstatus: %s" % status)
        if status:
            self.status.configure(text=status)
            self.status.pack(side="bottom", anchor="w", fill=None)
        else:
            self.status.pack_forget()

    def reset_links(self):
        self._hyper.reset()

    def insert_hyperlink(self, position, text, action, tag=None, tooltip=None):
        tags = self._hyper.add(action, tooltip)
        if type(tag) == list:
            tags = tags + tag
        elif tag != None:
            tags.append(tag)
        self.insert(position, text, tags)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        import tkinter as tk
    except ImportError:
        import Tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()
    tb = LinkScrolledText(root)
    tb.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    tb.insert_hyperlink("end", "Test", action=None, tooltip="This is a test")
    root.mainloop()
```

however if i move the mouse over the link before the window has been manually resized the window shrinks down when the label is packed, once the mouse moves off of the link the window re assumes its previous size. without manually setting the size or turning off `pack_propagate` how can i prevent this behaviour?

notes:
    windows xp (but want it to work on all platforms)
    tested in both python 2.7 and 3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order not to change the geometry of the text widget, you can place the status label inside instead of using pack:

```
def showstatus(self, status=None):
    print("showstatus: %s" % status)
    if status:
        self.status.configure(text=status)
        self.status.place(relx=0, rely=1, anchor='sw')
    else:
        self.status.place_forget()
```